# Filter NICs for general naming convention

Tags: powershell, dns, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to build a script to remotely change the DNS servers we are using on our remote servers. I have gotten stuck though. I have come up with this to get the Alias of the NICs listed:

```
$server = "servername"
$interfaces = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -ComputerName $server
$interfaces | ForEach{
    $aliasname = $_ | ForEach-Object { $_.NetConnectionID }
    $name = $_.GetRelated("Win32_PnPEntity") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    foreach($name in $aliasname){
        Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $server | select $name, Description, IPAddress, DNSServerSearchOrder |  Format-Table -AutoSize
    }
}
```

but the problem is I only want to change the DNS of one NIC and the NICs on the different servers may have a similar name but not always exactly the same. It may also not always be the same number NIC. I wanted to use something to exclude the wrong NIC so I tried something like

```
    foreach($name in $aliasname | Where-Object -Property $name -contains "WhatIAmLookingFor"){
        Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $server | select $name, Description, IPAddress, DNSServerSearchOrder |  Format-Table -AutoSize
    }
}
```

but it still returns both NICs. I have tried quite a few ways to make it exclude the NIC I don't want to change and only include the one I want but I usually either get nothing back or get both NICs. I also know most will say to try

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration-Filter 'IpEnabled=True' -computername $server
```

or

```
$nic = @(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration-Filter 'IpEnabled=True' -computername $server)[0]
```

but the problem is that none of the servers nics are standard other than following the general naming convention. So selecting the IpEnabled=True may cause me to also change a NIC being used to connect to a network that is not owned by my company. Same with only selecting the 1st NIC.  Any help with this issue is very much appreciated.

Comment: In the first code block, you define variable `$name` using `$name = $_.GetRelated(...)`. However, you immediately destroy that by using the same variable as the leftmost variable in the foreach loop `foreach($name in $aliasname)`. Use a different variable name there.

Comment: As this is Server 2008R2 what Powershell version do you have? They changed a lot between v2 and v5

Comment: if you know dms server ip address which you need to change you can get NIC with this DNS ip and replace it

Comment: This is v5. Thank you for the recommendation I changed the variable. It was working the way I had it as well. It did not seem to overwrite the variable but I can see how it seemed like it may have.

Comment: Victor I do know the DNS of the NIC I need to change how would I filter for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$server = "servername"
$excludedNic= "nic to exclude"
$interfaces = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -ComputerName $server -Filter "NetConnectionID!='$($excludedNic)'"
foreach($interface in $interfaces){
    if($null -ne $interface.NetConnectionID){
        Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $server -Filter "Description='$($interface.name)' " |Select-Object @{Name='NicName'; Expression={$interface.NetConnectionID}},  Description, IPAddress, DNSServerSearchOrder
    }
}
```